# How to avoid page reload after CSS change in Ionic/angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular-cli

I'm using ionic4 (angular6) with livereload.

**My Requirement - To load css in browser Instantly, without reloading entire page**.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try --no-livereload?

Comment: If you're using the CLI than that would be the expected behavior that as a file being watched changes it does a quick recompile as opposed to say just changing css on the user agent. I'm afraid what you're asking doesn't work the way you're hoping.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this worked out of the box in Ionic 3. I need a solution here too.

Comment: @RemiSture Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @DanAbrey no, unfortunately not.

Answer (score -1):

Just hit **STRG + S** after your changes in your .scss file

Here an [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17jbTrt0MLbzWfrpl2b8ySnh9DZHPlp6M/view?usp=sharing) how it works.

Comment: Thanks for video, but what is STRG?

Answer (score -3):

It reloads autmatically when you just save the changes on your .scss file. You dont have to reload the page in your browser.